# Excel formula to match characters against last 2 or 3 characters of another cell?

Tags: excel-formula

Say I have a set of values in column A that looks like this:

A-1-167

AB-21-16

A-1-BB-17

B-1-89

The common thing being that after the last dash, there could be two or three numbers.

In column B, I would have information about each cell to the left in A.

In another sheet, I have two columns: A would contain two or three numbers; for B, I need a formula that would, for example:

If A has a value of 89, I want to have the information for B-1-89 that's located in column B of other sheet. Meaning, I need a way to identify the numbers after the last dash in column A of sheet 1.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In one simple formula:

VLOOKUP will allow the use of Wild Cards:

```
=VLOOKUP("*-" & D1,A:B,2,FALSE)
```

The `"*-"` adds the wild card and the `-` to what is ever in D1.  So it will only look at the last grouping.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In **C1** enter:

```
=--MID(A1,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-",CHAR(1),LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-",""))))+1,255)
```

and copy down.  Column **C** extracts the phrase following the last dash.:

[image]

Now we can use *MATCH()* and *INDEX()*.  Put the lookup value in, say **D1**, and in **E1**:

```
=INDEX(B1:B4,MATCH(D1,C1:C4,0))
```

[image]

Comment: Your solution is more flexible than mine since it doesn't depend on the final field having length either 2 or 3.

Comment: @JohnColeman  Both are good solutions............the key concept is to isolate that last number-set.

Comment: `=VLOOKUP("*-" & D1,A:B,2,FALSE)`

Answer (score 2):

If it is always either 2 or 3 digits, you could check if the final 3 characters start with  `-` and act accordingly:

The key formula in `B1` (or whatever column you want this in) is:

```
=IF(MID(TRIM(A1),LEN(TRIM(A1))-2,1) = "-",RIGHT(TRIM(A1),2),RIGHT(TRIM(A1),3))
```

(The `TRIM` is to guard against inadvertent trailing white space, which coulr throw off the counts)

Output (after copying down):

[image]